# convert streamed buffers to utf8-string

Tags: node.js

I want to make a HTTP-request using node.js to load some text from a webserver. Since the response can contain much text (some Megabytes) I want to process each text chunk separately. I can achieve this using the following code:

```
var req = http.request(reqOptions, function(res) {
    ...
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function(textChunk) {
        // process utf8 text chunk
    });
});
```

This seems to work without problems. However I want to support HTTP-compression, so I use zlib:

```
var zip = zlib.createUnzip();

// NO res.setEncoding('utf8') here since we need the raw bytes for zlib
res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    // do something like checking the number of bytes downloaded
    zip.write(chunk); // give the raw bytes to zlib, s.b.
});

zip.on('data', function(chunk) {
    // convert chunk to utf8 text:
    var textChunk = chunk.toString('utf8');

    // process utf8 text chunk
});
```

This can be a problem for multi-byte characters like `'\u00c4'` which consists of two bytes: `0xC3` and `0x84`. If the first byte is covered by the first chunk (`Buffer`) and the second byte by the second chunk then `chunk.toString('utf8')` will produce incorrect characters at the end/beginning of the text chunk. How can I avoid this?

Hint: I still need the buffer (more specifically the number of bytes in the buffer) to limit the number of downloaded bytes. So using `res.setEncoding('utf8')` like in the first example code above for non-compressed data does not suit my needs.

Answer (score 318, accepted):

### Single Buffer

If you have a single `Buffer` you can use its [`toString`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) method that will convert all or part of the binary contents to a string using a specific encoding. It defaults to `utf8` if you don't provide a parameter, but I've explicitly set the encoding in this example.

```
var req = http.request(reqOptions, function(res) {
    ...

    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        var textChunk = chunk.toString('utf8');
        // process utf8 text chunk
    });
});
```

### Streamed Buffers

If you have streamed buffers like in the question above where the first byte of a multi-byte `UTF8`-character may be contained in the first `Buffer` (chunk) and the second byte in the second `Buffer` then you should use a [`StringDecoder`](http://nodejs.org/api/string_decoder.html). :

```
var StringDecoder = require('string_decoder').StringDecoder;

var req = http.request(reqOptions, function(res) {
    ...
    var decoder = new StringDecoder('utf8');

    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        var textChunk = decoder.write(chunk);
        // process utf8 text chunk
    });
});
```

This way bytes of *incomplete* characters are buffered by the `StringDecoder` until all required bytes were written to the decoder.

Comment: You can also to chunk.toString('utf8');

Comment: Please add the above suggestion in your answer as an update for the benefit of others. Many thanks !

Comment: @joshperry: sry, but as my question-text explains: `chunk.toString('utf8')` does not always work because of multi-byte characters in UTF8. I don't get why you changed my answer which explicitly overcome this problem by using a `StringDecoder`. Do I miss something here? Has `node` changed something?

Comment: @Biggie Sorry man, I did exactly what everyone else that came here from Google did. Came looking for "convert buffer to utf8 string" and found the answer had a hugely rated comment that answered the question topic the best. I agreed with FacePalm and updated the answer. If you revert the answer, I would change the question topic to something like "decoding streaming utf8 buffers".

Comment: I changed the topic-title and edited the answer. It now shows both solutions: converting streamed buffers and a single buffer using `toString`.

Comment: How do I get the entirety of the buffer after it has all been received? i.e. the whole string (accessing `textChunk` returns only the string that was received that event)

Comment: Thanks for showing how to properly deal with the situation where multi-byte characters are split across chunks. Many other resources on the internet ignore this completely, which leads to buggy code which often won't fail until it's in production.

Answer (score -5):

```
var fs = require("fs");

function readFileLineByLine(filename, processline) {
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
    var s = "";
    stream.on("data", function(data) {
        s += data.toString('utf8');
        var lines = s.split("\n");
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length - 1; i++)
            processline(lines[i]);
        s = lines[lines.length - 1];
    });

    stream.on("end",function() {
        var lines = s.split("\n");
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
            processline(lines[i]);
    });
}

var linenumber = 0;
readFileLineByLine(filename, function(line) {
    console.log(++linenumber + " -- " + line);
});
```

Comment: This code should be avoid as it does not support multi-byte code points (and the line splitting logic is not relevant to the question).