# NodeJS child process stdout are all numbers

Tags: node.js, stdout, child-process

I'm writing some node.js scripts to kick off a child process. Code snippet is as below.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn; 
var child = spawn ('node', ['script.js'])

child.stdout.on('data', 
    function (data) {
        logger.verbose('tail output: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    }
);

child.stderr.on('data',
    function (data) {
        logger.error('err data: ' + data);
    }
);
```

Script runs well except that child process's stdout and stderr prints only numeric outputs:

Sample output:

```
   108,34,44,34,105,110,99,114,101,97,109,101,110,116,97,108,95,112,111,108,108,105
```

How do I convert these numeric values to readable string?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to use data.toString('utf8'); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121775/convert-streamed-buffers-to-utf8-string

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`data` is an array buffer. Call its toString method `JSON.stringify(data.toString('utf8'))`