# Not getting proper response in node js by using node-rest-client middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I am a newby in Node js, after hit HubSpot api through node js by using node-rest-middleware am getting below kind of response. Why?

```
<Buffer 7b 22 76 69 64 22 3a 35 2c 22 63 61 6e 6f 6e 69 63 61 6c 2d 76 69 64 22 3a 35 2c 22 6d 65 72 67 65 64 2d 76 69 64 73 22 3a 5b 5d 2c 22 70 6f 72 74 61 ... >
```

Here is my snippet please take a look

```
var args = {
    data: formData,
    headers:{"Content-Type": "application/json"}
};

client.post(hubURL, args, function(data,response) {
      // parsed response body as js object 
      console.log(data, "data in client post");
});
```

and formData is a proper valid json 
what am doing wrong

**updated**
here is the snapshot
[image]

Comment: Could not find the middleware in npm. Try utf8 encoding the buffer. Or, just use https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Comment: @SwarajGiri unable to use request middleware. I haven't see how to hit rest api through request. here is the link https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client

Comment: Start by converting the buffer to a string and see what's inside. That might give you a hint

Comment: updated my answer, this should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `data` you are getting is a [*Buffer*](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end). Try converting it to string like bellow.

```
if(Buffer.isBuffer(data)){
    data = data.toString('utf8');
}
console.log(data);
```

Comment: @Mriunjay thanks alot now it's working fine but could you please tell me why response in that format

Comment: Just a typo in encoding constant,  See the edit in answer

Comment: @TheMechanic I think in nodejs any http-request bydefault gives data as Buffer.

Comment: @GauravGupta I don't think that was a problem `utf-8` works for me.

Comment: Nope when I hit another api it gives me proper json object response

Comment: @Mritunjay I referred to https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer . But, if utf-8 works for you and its legitimate as well, then we can revert the edit. As far as documentation is concerned, i could not see utf-8. Please let me know if you come through it in documentation.

Comment: @GauravGupta it's fine, No need to revert it. Thanx for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

This is data formatting issue, you are getting data in Buffer format and you want it in String format.

You can explicitly do the conversion.

You can use [toString()](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) of the Buffer, which will convert Buffer format into String format. [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121775/convert-streamed-buffers-to-utf8-string)

```
var yourStringData = data.toString('utf8');
```

Answer (score 0):

The Buffer should be converted to a String

```
client.post(baseUri + "tradingpartners/",args, function (data, response) {
    // parsed response body as js object
  console.log(data.toString('utf8'));
});
```

Comment: This doesn't really add anything to the already accepted answer.