# NodeJS Buffer - reading data results in garbage characters

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to read *some data* from *some devices* which are connected to my socket server written in NodeJS. Data is received as binary stream and I am following device specification to read each chunk properly. Specification is similar to this:

```
byte | size | type          | description
-------------------------------------------
   0 |    2 | unsigned int  | whatever...
   2 |    4 | unsigned int  | irrelevant...
   6 |  var | character str | etc...
```

When I receive data like this, I am reading each chunk with specific Buffer method, for example:

```
// example code
const tid = data.readUInt16BE(0);
const dataLength = data.readUInt32BE(2);
const rest = data.toString('utf8', 6);
```

The problem I have is reading this variable-length data. I am using `data.toString('utf8', 6)` (without `end` defined because I need just the rest of the data) but my `rest` variable contains some weird characters which I suspect are carriage returns but are showing differently in console every time. For example:

```
// in each response here, everything before $ character is garbage
// 'clean' response should look like:
// OK
// $DATA=1234567890
// $DATA=0987654321
// etc...

// example code, 1st try
const rest = data.toString('utf8', 6);
console.log(rest);
// results in:
// OK
// ��$DATA=1234567890
// ��$DATA=0987654321
// etc...

// example code, 2nd try
const rest = data.toString('utf8', 6);
console.log(rest);
// results in:
// OK
// i�$DATA=1234567890
// i�$DATA=0987654321
// etc...

// example code, 3rd try
const rest = data.toString('utf8', 6);
console.log(rest);
// results in:
// OK
// UB$DATA=1234567890
// UB$DATA=0987654321
// etc...

// example code, 4th try
const rest = data.toString('utf8', 6);
console.log(rest);
// results in:
// OK
// � $DATA=1234567890
// � $DATA=0987654321
// etc...

// well, you get the point...
```

The thing is that there are always 2 characters in the beginning of each line which I just cannot figure out what they are and why do they appear.

As I said, I *think* that this happens because of carriage return, so I tried to replace it in different ways:

```
const rest = data.toString('utf8', 6).replace('\r', '');
// or (makes no sense, but let's try anyways)
const rest = data.toString('utf8', 6).replace(/[\r]/g, '');
// or (hoped that this one will really work)
const rest = data.toString('utf8', 6).replace(/[\n\r]/g, '\n');
// etc...
```

but, of course, nothing works from my attempts, garbage characters always show up.

My questions are: how to figure out which characters are these and what can I try to do to remove them?

Comment: Have you tried any other encoding, like ascii?

Comment: Uh!!! No, I have not! :))) Jeez! Let me see if that's going to work :)

Comment: Ah, unfortunately this didn't help :/ It just resulted in not displaying � characters anymore, but there are still 2 _random_ characters within `ascii` range :/

Comment: Can you convert data (which is basically a byte array) to a list of numbers and add that to the question?

Comment: Sure, I'll try to do that in a bit and will update my question...

Comment: Since you are working with chunks, you should check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12122668/8029464) out!