# Buffer to String?

Tags: node.js, string, buffer, decode

What is the Advantage of method 1 over 2 for string decoding purpose?

Method 1:

```
const { StringDecoder } = require('string_decoder')
const decoder = new StringDecoder('utf-8')
let body = ''
req.on('data', data => {
  body += decoder.write(data)
})
```

Method 2:

```
let body = ''
req.on('data', data => {
  body += data.toString()
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the first byte of a multi-byte UTF8-character may be contained in the first Buffer (chunk) and the second byte in the second Buffer then you should use a [StringDecoder.](https://nodejs.org/api/string_decoder.html)

> Reference:
>   [convert streamed buffers to utf8-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121775/convert-streamed-buffers-to-utf8-string)

Comment: Thanks Sir I got that!