# Unable to convert buffer to string

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, buffer

```
function parseMessage (buff){
    let obs = [];

    let done = false;
    let offset = 0;
    let size_bytes = 4;
    while(!done){
        let message_size = buff.readUIntBE(offset, size_bytes);
        let message = buff.readUIntBE(size_bytes+offset,Number(message_size));
        console.log(buff,message.toString());
        offset = size_bytes+offset+message_size;
        try {
            let o = JSON.parse(message.toString());
            if (o && typeof o === "object") {
                obs.push(o);
            }
        }
        catch (e) {console.log(e);console.log(message.toString());}
        if(offset >= buff.length){
            done = true;
        }
    }

    return obs;
};


let buff = new Buffer("\0\0\0\02ab");
parseMessage(buff);
```

outputs `<Buffer 00 00 00 02 61 62> '24930'` instead of `<Buffer 00 00 00 02 61 62> 'ab'`

The `2` prepended to `ab` describes the length.This is because the buffer will be used with sockets.

Also if I do:

```
message.toString(16)
```

I am able to get the ascii codes `6162` but they still aren't characters.

Comment: did you try ```message.toString('binary')``` or ```message.toString('latin1')``` ?

Comment: Both of those throw `RangeError: toString() radix argument must be between 2 and 36`

Comment: would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121775/convert-streamed-buffers-to-utf8-string) help?

Comment: The suggestion for the stream buffer (which I don't think this is) throws `<Buffer 00 00 00 02 61 62> ''`. The suggestion for the single buffer is the same as what I have because .toString() uses utf8 as default.

Comment: could you please try this? ```let message = buff.slice(size_bytes + offset, size_bytes + offset + message_size)```