# Node.js - How to get stream into string

Tags: string, node.js, stream, node.js-stream

I have got stream and I need to get stream content into string. I stream from internet using http.get. I also write stream into file, but I don't want to write file and after that open the same file and read from it...
So I need to convert stream into string
Thanks for all advices...

Comment: You're question is far too vague. So do you want to convert the incoming data to a string, or write it to disk? Some example code would help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing node.js stream into a string variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623798/writing-node-js-stream-into-a-string-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the second nested function, try the toString() method on the stream. This can then be piped wherever you want it to go, and you can also write a through() method that can assign it to a variable or use it directly in the one function.

```
var http = require('http');

var string = '';
var request = http.get('http://www.google.cz', function (err, data){
  if (err) console.log(err);
  string = data.toString();
  //any other code you may want
});
//anything else
```

One last note--the http.get() method takes two parameters: the url, and a callback. This requires two parameters, and you may have been getting nothing because it was an empty error message.

Comment: I think this only works here because http.get returns an extended stream, in general Readable streams do not have a toString method which works this way.

Answer (score 1):

```
var http = require('http');

var string = '';
var request = http.get("http://www.google.cz", function(response) {       
    response.on('data', function(response){
      string += response.toString();

  }); 
    response.on('end', function(string){
      console.log(string);
    });  
  });
```

This works for sure. I am using it.