# Retrieve data from a ReadableStream object?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

How may I get information from a `ReadableStream` object?

I am using the Fetch API and I don't see this to be clear from the documentation.

The body is being returned as a `ReadableStream` and I would simply like to access a property within this stream. Under Response in the browser dev tools, I appear to have this information organised into properties, in the form of a JavaScript object.

```
fetch('http://192.168.5.6:2000/api/car', obj)
    .then((res) => {
        if(!res.ok) {
            console.log("Failure:" + res.statusText);
            throw new Error('HTTP ' + res.status);
        } else {
            console.log("Success :" + res.statusText);
            return res.body // what gives?
        }
    })
```

Comment: @FrancescoPezzella Thanks for the response. I have tried `response.Body.json()` , but I am getting _italic_ TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined _italic_ . 
Is this because the bodyUsed property is also set to false? 

However I can view this body under the response tab in browser developer tools. There is an error message which I'd like to retrieve.

Comment: So your issue is purely related to the error 400 condition? What happens if you change the handler to `console.log(res.json());`? Do you see the data you are expecting?

Comment: @noob Are you trying to read the response as a stream if `res.status == 200`?

Comment: Is it just me or that documentation is *plain* wrong? I did fix it with the solutions on this answers though.

Comment: I know it has been a while but for the sake of keeping stackoverflow great, please just accept the right answer. The one with over 200 upvotes.

Answer (score 494, accepted):

In order to access the data from a `ReadableStream` you need to call one of the conversion methods (docs available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/body)).

As an example:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
  .then(function(response) {
    // The response is a Response instance.
    // You parse the data into a useable format using `.json()`
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(data) {
    // `data` is the parsed version of the JSON returned from the above endpoint.
    console.log(data);  // { "userId": 1, "id": 1, "title": "...", "body": "..." }
  });
```

---

**EDIT:** If your data return type is not JSON or you don't want JSON then use `text()`

As an example:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  }).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data); // this will be a string
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried this and am still getting the same error where res.body is undefined. I am able to retrieve the status however in first then() function with res.status. It seems that only the body is a ReadableStream object. It does seem to have a property locked, which is set to true?

Comment: Where are you trying to access `res.body` (this isn't part of my example)? Can you share some sample code in your original question to make it clearer where your problem might be.

Comment: I tried accessing res.body from the json response that was returned in first .then() function. I have added a sample to my original question for more clarity. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, using react and request native, and wondering what in the world to do with a ReadableStream, and this did the trick. ++

Comment: Just a headsup, seems like a no-brainer, but make sure the backend you're hitting is actually providing valid JSON! Definitely not speaking from experience.

Comment: What if the response of the ReadableStream is an image?

Comment: @Azurespot It depends on what you want to do with the Image. You could call one of these methods https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body, for example `const imageBlob = await response.blob();` and then `const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob); htmlImageElement.src = objectUrl;`. The returned URL is released automatically when the document is unloaded. But if your page has dynamic use, you should release it explicitly by calling window.URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl). Or use a FileReader.

Comment: thank you so so so much for this resposne! I was bashing my face against everything not understanding all this "readable stream" api documentation and its all about chunks & text files and crap im not using. this worked! I haven't done backend work in over a year so i'm so rusty, this looks like what I used to learn/write and I knew I was forgetting something like this - this was it!

Comment: Link is broken, try this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream

Answer (score 123):

Some people may find an `async` example useful:

```
var response = await fetch("https://httpbin.org/ip");
var body = await response.json(); // .json() is asynchronous and therefore must be awaited
```

`json()` converts the response's body from a `ReadableStream` to a json object.

The `await` statements must be wrapped in an `async` function, however you can run `await` statements directly in the console of Chrome (as of version 62).

Comment: Sometimes the real answer for you really is #2 haha, it makes sense why they'd make .json() asynchronous but it wasn't immediately obvious

Comment: This is correct, and the most straightforward.

Answer (score 50):

`response.json()` returns a Promise. Try ...

```
res.json().then(body => console.log(body));
```

where `response` is the result of the `fetch(...)`

Comment: I tried this, and it printed out the Promise instead of the body.

Comment: Try to chain the `.then` calls: `fetch(...).then(res => res.json()).then(data => console.log(data))`

Answer (score 37):

You may have asked the wrong question to solve your problem, but here is an answer to your actual question. An inspiration may be the source code of the Node.js [`stream/consumers` module](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/lib/stream/consumers.js).

`res.body` is a [`ReadableStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream) that emits chunks as [`Uint8Array`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array). Note that `ReadableStream` objects created elsewhere may emit other data types than `Uint8Array`, and the methods outlined in this answer need to be adjusted in those cases.

There are multiple ways to consume such a stream:

## Convert a stream to a `Uint8Array`

### Using `new Response(stream).arrayBuffer()`

If you want to retrieve the whole content of the stream in one go, the easiest way would is to wrap it in a [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object. You can then use one of the several [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#instance_methods) to retrieve the object as a string, a JSON object, an array buffer or something else. For example, to retrieve it as an array buffer:

```js
export async function streamToArrayBuffer(stream: ReadableStream<Uint8Array>): Promise<Uint8Array> {
   return new Uint8Array(await new Response(stream).arrayBuffer());
}
```

Note that `new Response(stream)` only works for `Uint8Array` streams. If the stream emits any other type (such as strings), it will result in a `TypeError: Received non-Uint8Array chunk` error.

### Using `stream.getReader()`

The following function will collect all the chunks in a single `Uint8Array`:

```js
function concatArrayBuffers(chunks: Uint8Array[]): Uint8Array) {
    const result = new Uint8Array(chunks.reduce((a, c) => a + c.length, 0);
    let offset = 0;
    for (const chunk of chunks) {
        result.set(chunk, offset);
        offset += chunk.length;
    }
    return result;
}

export async function streamToArrayBuffer(stream: ReadableStream<Uint8Array>): Promise<Uint8Array> {
    const chunks: Uint8Array[] = [];
    const reader = stream.getReader();
    while (true) {
        const { done, value } = await reader.read();
        if (done) {
            break;
        } else {
            chunks.push(value);
        }
    }
    return concatArrayBuffers(chunks);
}
```

### Using async iterator

`ReadableStream` implements the [async iterator protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#the_async_iterator_and_async_iterable_protocols). However, this is [not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream#browser_compatibility) by most browsers yet, but in Node.js you can already use it (using TypeScript, you will have to use the `NodeJS.ReadableStream` interface, see [this discussion](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/discussions/65542#discussioncomment-6071004)).

The following code will collect all the chunks into a single `Uint8Array`:

```js
export async function streamToArrayBuffer(stream: ReadableStream<Uint8Array>): Promise<Uint8Array> {
    const chunks: Uint8Array[] = [];
    for await (const chunk of stream) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
    }
    return concatArrayBuffers(chunks);
}
```

In the future when browser support [`Array.fromAsync()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fromAsync), this can be shortened to:

```js
export async function streamToArrayBuffer(stream: ReadableStream<Uint8Array>): Promise<Uint8Array> {
    return concatArrayBuffers(await Array.fromAsync(stream));
}
```

## Convert a stream to a `string`

### Using `new Response(stream).text()`

Just like described above for an array buffer, a stream of `Uint8Array` can be converted to a string by using `Response.text()`:

```js
export async function streamToString(stream: ReadableStream<Uint8Array>): Promise<string> {
   return await new Response(stream).text();
}
```

### Using `TextDecoderStream`

[`TextDecoderStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoderStream) will convert the stream of `UInt8Array` chunks into a stream of `string` chunks. This way you can collect the contents of a stream as a string directly. Note that browser support in Firefox has only been added in September 2022, so you might not want to use this in production just yet.

```js
export async function streamToText(stream: ReadableStream<Uint8Array>): Promise<string> {
    let result = '';
    const reader = stream.pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream()).getReader();
    while (true) {
        const { done, value } = await reader.read();
        if (done) {
            break;
        }

        result += value;
    }
    return result;
}
```

In browsers that support it, you can also consume this stream of strings using the async iterator protocol:

```js
export async function streamToText(stream: ReadableStream<Uint8Array>): Promise<string> {
    let result = '';
    for (const chunk of stream.pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream()).getReader())
        result += chunk;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or in browsers that support `Array.fromAsync()`, even shorter:

```js
export async function streamToText(stream: ReadableStream<Uint8Array>): Promise<string> {
    const chunks = await Array.fromAsync(stream.pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream()).getReader()));
    return chunks.join("");
}
```

### Using `TextDecoder`

To convert the `Uint8Array`s generated by some of the functions above to a string, you can then use [`TextDecoder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder):

```js
const buffer = await streamToArrayBuffer(res.body);
const text = new TextDecoder().decode(buffer);
```

Note that this should only been used on the whole content, not on individual `UInt8Array` chunks, as some characters may consist of multiple bytes and might be split up between chunks.

## Convert a stream to a JSON object

### Using `new Response(stream).json()`

Just like described above for an array buffer and a string, a stream of `Uint8Array` can be parsed as JSON by using `Response.json()`:

```js
export async function streamToJson(stream: ReadableStream<Uint8Array>): Promise<unknown> {
   return await new Response(stream).json();
}
```

### Using `JSON.parse()`

Use any of the methods above to convert the stream to a string and then use `JSON.parse()` to parse that string.

Comment: thanks for actually answering the question

Comment: For those who have a `ReadableStream` and just want a simple/easy one-liner to get the text out of it, a short hack is to wrap it in a new `Response` (or `Request`) object and then use the `text` method: `await new Response(request.body).text()`. Posted an answer for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74237249/11950764).

Answer (score 29):

For those who have a `ReadableStream` and want to get the text out of it, a short hack is to wrap it in a new `Response` (or `Request`) and then use the `text` method:

```js
let text = await new Response(yourReadableStream).text();
```

Answer (score 21):

Little bit late to the party but had some problems with getting something useful out from a `ReadableStream` produced from a Odata $batch request using the Sharepoint Framework.

Had similar issues as OP, but the solution in my case was to use a different conversion method than `.json()`. In my case `.text()` worked like a charm. Some fiddling was however necessary to get some useful JSON from the textfile.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. I am sending an Illuminate http response from my Laravel server with a simple `return $data;`. I was finally able to read this response in the browser with `fetch(...).then(response => response.text()).then(data => console.log(data));`

Comment: i have an api which return jwt token and .then(response => response.text()).then(data => console.log(data)); return undefined in that case

Answer (score 20):

Note that you can only read a stream once, so in some cases, you may need to clone the response in order to repeatedly read it:

```
fetch('example.json')
  .then(res=>res.clone().json())
  .then( json => console.log(json))

fetch('url_that_returns_text')
  .then(res=>res.clone().text())
  .then( text => console.log(text))
```

Answer (score 15):

If you just want the response as text and don't want to convert it into JSON, use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text and then `then` it to get the actual result of the promise:

```
fetch('city-market.md')
  .then(function(response) {
    response.text().then((s) => console.log(s));
  });
```

or

```
fetch('city-market.md')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(function(myText) {
    console.log(myText);
  });
```

Comment: Yay for CityMarket.md <3

Answer (score 4):

I dislike the chaining thens. The second then does not have access to status. As stated before 'response.json()' returns a promise. Returning the then result of 'response.json()' in a acts similar to a second then. It has the added bonus of being in scope of the response.

```
return fetch(url, params).then(response => {
    return response.json().then(body => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            return body
        } else {
            throw body
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: The chaining `then` helps you retrieve the final resolved value (the `body`). Nesting them prevents you from being able to get the `body` value without a callback or some mechanism of the sort. Imagine this: `let body = await fetch(...).then(res => res.json()).then(data => data)`. This wouldn't work in the nested way. To check for `response.status` you can always `throw` an exception inside the first `then`, and add a `catch` to the whole promise chain.

Comment: AGREE. Preferred in enterprise environment. : )

Answer (score 4):

Another approach could be to consume/process the incoming stream of data in chunks:

```
async function toJSON(body) {
  const reader = body.getReader();
  const decoder = new TextDecoder();
  const chunks = [];

  async function read() {
    const { done, value } = await reader.read();

    if (done) {
      return JSON.parse(chunks.join(''));
    }

    const chunk = decoder.decode(value, { stream: true });
    chunks.push(chunk);
    return read();
  }

  return read();
}

const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
const jsonData = await toJSON(response.body);

console.log(jsonData);
```

This approach is especially useful when the incoming data is *too* large or if you wish to start processing the data as soon as its chunks are available.

Wrote a [blog post](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-convert-javascript-readablestream-object-to-json) for those interested in learning more.

Comment: Other answers lose the interest of using a readable stream by calling methods that wait and return the final result at the end whereas yours allows to use the incoming data. Keep up the good work. Your blog post is helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

here is how I implemented it. In this case the api is returning a ndjson as a stream, and I am reading it in chunks. In ndjson format, data is split by new lines, so each line by itself is a basic json which I parsed and added to fetchedData variable.

```
var fetchedData = [];

fetch('LinkGoesHere', {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer TokenGoesHere' // this part is irrelevant and you may not need it for your application
    }
})
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
    }
    return response.body.getReader();
})
.then(reader => {
    let partialData = '';

    // Read and process the NDJSON response
    return reader.read().then(function processResult(result) {
        if (result.done) {
            return;
        }

        partialData += new TextDecoder().decode(result.value, { stream: true });
        const lines = partialData.split('\n');

        for (let i = 0; i < lines.length - 1; i++) {
            const json = JSON.parse(lines[i]);
            fetchedData.push(json); // Store the parsed JSON object in the array
        }

        partialData = lines[lines.length - 1];

        return reader.read().then(processResult);
    });
})
.then(() => {
    // At this point, fetchedData contains all the parsed JSON objects
    console.log(fetchedData);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error('Fetch error:', error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

const resText = await response.json();
//returns string

const resJson = JSON.parse(resText);
//objectified

sometimes (especially when you are using an api written in another language), response.json returns string. You should treat it like res.body and parse it, then you have the object. Hope it helps.

Comment: `const resText = await response.json();` returns a JSON object not a string, the second line will throw an error, trying to parse a JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **React Native**, it used to not be possible to do this.

But streaming is now possible with https://github.com/react-native-community/fetch.

This was actually a [bug](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27741) that was never addressed by RN team for a while, and this repo emerged to provide a better fetch that complies with WHATWG Spec

> This is a fork of GitHub's fetch polyfill, the fetch implementation React Native currently provides. This project features an alternative fetch implementation directy built on top of React Native's Networking API instead of XMLHttpRequest for performance gains. At the same time, it aims to fill in some gaps of the WHATWG specification for fetch, namely the support for text streaming.

Here's how to use it:

## Install

This concise steps are from hours of debugging, and I dont want to waste your time.

```
$ npm install react-native-fetch-api --save
```

Now install polyfills:

```
$ npm install react-native-polyfill-globals
```

Use the polyfill with fetch:

Add the following code to the top of your app's entry file, index.js, located at the root of your project. Now your new Fetch is available globally.

```
import { polyfill as polyfillFetch } from 'react-native-polyfill-globals/src/fetch';
polyfill();
```

Now you can use the stream object like the normal browser fetch. Make sure to specify the option `textStreaming` true.

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', { reactNative: { textStreaming: true } })
  .then(response => response.body)
  .then(stream => ...)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -3):

I just had the same problem for over 12 hours before reading next, just in case this helps anyone. When using nextjs inside your _api page you will need to use JSON.stringify(whole-response) and then send it back to your page using res.send(JSON.stringify(whole-response)) and when it's received on the client side you need to translate it back into json format so that it's usable. This can be kinda figured out by reading their serialization section. Hope it helps.

Comment: Consider formatting your code

Comment: I had the same problem about response.json() is undefined and it looks like that i did not await the fefch method: Always make sure to await asynchronous actions guys , const response = await fetch(url+path)