# ReactJS app is unable to fetch data using REST API call

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to develop sample Reactjs web app, where trying to use REST API and fetch some json data. Please see the code.

I am checking in chrome browser after executing the code locally in visual studio, but there is nothing printed in chrome console log. I think, the following code doesn't fetch the data. I didn't find anything wrong in this code. Could someone please help guiding me?

I have used ***axios*** and URL : https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users to fetch the data

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css'
import App from './App'
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker'

import axios from 'axios'

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
registerServiceWorker()

var element = React.createElement(
  'h1',
  { className: 'greeting' },
  'Test Welcome Message.!'
)
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'))
registerServiceWorker()

export default class ItemLister extends React.Component {
  state = {
    persons: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(response => {
      // Handle service success response
      console.log(response.data)

      const persons = response.data;
      this.setState({ persons });
    })
  }

  render() {
    return <ul>{this.state. persons.map(person => <li>{person.name}</li>)}</ul>
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are not rendering ItemLister. Or is this done somewhere else?

Comment: Your `setState()` is updating state property `persons` and not `products`. You are not seeing the results of this because you are looping/mapping over `products` and not `persons`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The big problem (if nothing is printing) is probably that your component is not rendering.** You are defining, but not rendering `ItemLister`. It needs to be rendered somewhere. To fix this easily, move the definition of `ItemLister` *above*  `ReactDOM.render`, and render `<ItemLister />` instead of `element`. I think that should render the element.

*If the component is not rendered, the code within it (including the axios fetch) will not run.*

So here's what your code should look like:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css'
import App from './App'
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker'

import axios from 'axios'

export default class ItemLister extends React.Component {
  state = {
    persons: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(response => {
      // Handle service success response
      console.log(response.data)

      const persons = response.data;
      this.setState({ persons });
    })
  }

  render() {
    return <ul>{this.state. persons.map(person => <li>{person.name}</li>)}</ul>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ItemLister />, document.getElementById('root'))
registerServiceWorker()
```

---

If that starts the component logging, I think you may run into another issue:

The issue appears to be not with your React code (ie, any component-level issues), but rather with the response from the API not matching your expectations. I ran the following test requests in the Chrome console (with `fetch`, which works similarly to `axios`):

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(resp => console.log(resp))
```

That returned a response object that looks like this:

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: ""
type: "cors"
url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
```

First thing to notice is that there is no `data` attribute on this response. Second thing to notice is that `body` isn't a basic data type. So let's see what `body` is:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(resp => console.log(resp.body))
```

The logged response:

```
ReadableStream {}
```

Looks like `body` is a `ReadableStream {}`.

That probably means we need to ["unpack" the response into JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40385133/retrieve-data-from-a-readablestream-object), so that `resp.body` is a JSON object, not a `ReadableStream`.

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(resp => resp.json()).then(data => console.log(data))
```

Bingo. Here's the response:

```
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

An array of ten objects, which appear to be the users you want.

Comment: is there any other sanple REST api for free i can test it.

Comment: I need a help. If i want to add "header" after axios.get URL, how to do add header?

Comment: Axios takes a `configs` object as a second argument to `get`. I think all you need to do is pass `headers` in those configs as the docs outline: https://github.com/axios/axios#instance-methods

Answer (score 3):

Try this. You are doing .map on products but not on persons

```
   componentDidMount() {
           axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
     .then( ({data}) => {
          this.setState({ persons: data });
      })
   }
```

OR

```
  componentDidMount() {
          axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then( response => {
           this.setState({ persons: response.data });
       })
   }
```

Or try with fetch

```
   componentDidMount(){
 fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(resp => resp.json()).then(data => this.setState({ persons: data}))
     }
```

Also don’t forget to add key to li element. You need to add key to the parent element when you do loop like below

```
  <ul>
      { this.state.persons.map(person => <li key={person.id}> {person.name}</li>)}
 </ul>
```

If you don’t have unique id from data then add index as key like below

```
   <ul>
       { this.state.persons.map((person,index) => <li key={“Key”+index}>{person.name}</li>)}
   </ul>
```

Comment: I have updated the actual code. The problem is not fetching data and not showing in console as well -> console.log(response.data)

Comment: What if you directly access this url in browser https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users ? Do you get the response?

Comment: Yes, it gives a big json data

Comment: Ok if you do console.log(response) what do u get?

Comment: console.log(response) is also giving nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182446/discussion-between-think-twice-and-stella).