# How to get string response of fetch api and assign it to a variable?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, fetch-api

I am sending a request to backend with fetchApi and **the response is coming as a just only string (not in a json body)**

Here is my frontend code:

```
        async decryptText() {
    let response = await this.getDecryptedText(this.entry.text, this.user.userId)
    if(response){
        console.log(response)
    }
   }
        
async getDecryptedText(inputText: string, userId: number) {
    let url = "http://localhost:8080/getDecryptedText?textToDecrypt=" + inputText + "&userId=" + userId;
    return fetch(url);
  }
```

But I cannot parse the response like other json responses because it is just a string.

When I print it to console the output is this:
[image]

I just want to print on to console the response string

How can I get the string response and assign it to a variable ?

I have edited the code as on answers.

Comment: If it's not JSON then don't call `response.json()`.

Comment: Also `getDecryptedText()` is not declared as `async` so you can't `await` it.

Comment: If you're using Angular, you could also try [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient). It is a little more versatile.

Comment: i have edited the code and the output. still i cant print it  to console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` means wait until promise is resolved. so you should not use `.then`
callback function. It should be,

```
async decryptText() {
     let response = await this.getDecryptedText(this.entry.text, this.user.userId)

     // promise is resolved here with success or failure

     if(response){
         console.log(response)   // you should get result here
     }
}
```

Comment: i have edited the code and the output. still i cant print it  to console

Comment: `cosonole.log(response)` what does it print ?

Answer (score 1):

hope it help's you try this :

```
  decryptText() {
   this.getDecryptedText(this.entry.text, this.user.userId)
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(response => {
     console.log(response)
     })
   }
getDecryptedText(inputText, userId) {
 let url = "http://localhost:8080/getDecryptedText?textToDecrypt=" + inputText + "&userId=" + userId;
        return fetch(url);
  }
```

Comment: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0
SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Response.text() method

```js
 let response = await this.getDecryptedText(this.entry.text, this.user.userId)
  .then(res=>{
    if(res.ok){
      console.log(res.text())
    }
```

This might work. `res.ok` there is a boolean which says was request successful or not. You must use this because construction `if(res)` is useless — you always get response even if request failed.

Answer (score 0):

try to print like

```
console.log(response.body)
```

Because, you are getting body in your response.

Comment: doesnt work :( it prints whole body as readable stream

Comment: check your api on some api testing platforms like, postman, and show us the result.

Comment: I hope this solves your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/40403285/8129656