# Https request from react sending incorrect(null) values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, fetch-api

I have been trying to make a http PUT request for sending data to the server. Each time, when I try to send the request the data in the server becomes null. I have tested the server side code by sending correct format of data seems the server side is working fine. Going back to the client side code, I have noticed that during fetch operation the data in the response becomes in `ReadableStream`. Don't know actually what does that mean. Can anybody help me finding out the mistakes if it is possible from the below information.

I am trying to send the data from the react component:

```
updateData(data)
```

the format of the data I am trying to send is an Object:

```
{first:"first", second:"second"}
```

And then in my API handler:

```
const updateData = async (data) => {
const resource = await getResource('PUT', {
    data,
  });
const url = `${process.env.updateAPI}/Update`;
  return handleFetch(url, resource);
};
```

And then in my `handleFetch` function:

```
  const handleFetch = async (url, resource) => {
  const res = await fetch(url, resource);

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Request failed, status ${res.status}`);
  }

  const resData = await res.json();
  return resData;
};
```

`getResource` function is accepting the parameters and returns the required methods, data and the header where `'Content-Type': 'application/json',` is provided and handling the data like: `body = JSON.stringify(data);`

During debugging I have noticed that the res from `fetchHandlers` becomes like this:

[image]

I am actually confused, why in the body the data becomes `ReadableStream` instead of the actual data I am trying to send or is this the problem I am having null values. Can anybody help me with that?, it will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve data from a ReadableStream object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40385133/retrieve-data-from-a-readablestream-object)

Answer (score 1):

If your data return type is not JSON or you don't want JSON then use text()

As an example:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  }).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data); // this will be a string
  });
```

Comment: return data type is in my case is json