# Convert to base64 from response.body which is in readablestream format

Tags: javascript, typescript, http, base64

I have a http request in javascript that returns content of a file in the response. The `response.body` is in readablestream format. I need to get the file content in base64 format and upload in a different location. Can I know what is the best approach to convert the content to base64 string?

```
var url="httpurl";
var dataContent= await fetch(url);

var textContent= await dataContent.blob();
```

Next line is to make https call to upload a file with content in base64 string format.

I would like to know how the datacontent can be converted to base64 string.

`dataContent` is as in below image:

[image]

Comment: Can you post some examples of your code including what you have tried so far to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Added some example as requested

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40403285/3261454) has more info on how to get the response from a `ReadableStream`. Here's the main part with the base64 conversion included. The `base64encode` function is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26603875/3261454)

```
function base64encode(str: string): string {
  return btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(str)));
}

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  }).then(function(data) {
    const base64encodedData = base64encode(data);
    console.log(data); // this will be a string
  });
```