# "How can I resolve an issue when accessing 'request.body' in an async function, which returns a 'ReadableStream' object instead of the expected data?"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js13, next-api

When i create my CRUD in Nextjs13, typescript, and prisma
the GET method handler works correctly, but the PUT give me some errors and i want to know what i doing wrong

when y get the request its says to me:
Here is the request body:
ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: false }

here my code example:

```
export async function PUT(request: NextApiRequest) {
    const id = "1";
    console.log("aqui esta")
    console.log(request)
    const { name, description, price, image, category, tags, link, variantType, sizes, allOfSizes, status, rating, numberOfReviews } = await request.body;
  
    console.log("Here is the request body:");
    console.log(request.body);
    console.log("Here is the name and description:");
    console.log(name, description);
  
    if (!id) {
      return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ error: "Product ID is required" }), {
        status: 400,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });
    }
  
    try {
      const existingProduct = await prisma.product.findUnique({
        where: {
          id: String(id),
        },
      });
  
      if (!existingProduct) {
        console.log("Product not found");
        return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ error: "Product not found" }), {
          status: 404,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        });
      }
  
      const updatedProduct = await prisma.product.update({
        where: {
          id: String(id),
        },
        data: {
          name,
          description,
          price,
          image,
          category,
          tags: { set: tags || [] },
          link,
          variantType,
          sizes: { set: sizes || [] },
          allOfSizes: { set: allOfSizes || [] },
          status,
          rating,
          numberOfReviews,
        },
      });
  
      console.log("Product updated");
      return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(updatedProduct), {
        status: 200,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error updating product:", error);
      return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ error: "Internal Server Error" }), {
        status: 500,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });
    }}
```

the console output from my debugging:

```
 compiling /api/products/[id]/route (client and server)...
- event compiled client and server successfully in 626 ms (371 modules)
aqui esta el request ndoikoi
NextRequest [Request] {
  [Symbol(realm)]: {
    settingsObject: { baseUrl: undefined, origin: [Getter], policyContainer: [Object] }
  },
  [Symbol(state)]: {
    method: 'PUT',
    localURLsOnly: false,
    unsafeRequest: false,
    body: { stream: undefined, source: null, length: null },
    client: { baseUrl: undefined, origin: [Getter], policyContainer: [Object] },
    reservedClient: null,
    replacesClientId: '',
    window: 'client',
    keepalive: false,
    serviceWorkers: 'all',
    initiator: '',
    destination: '',
    priority: null,
    origin: 'client',
    policyContainer: 'client',
    referrer: 'client',
    referrerPolicy: '',
    mode: 'cors',
    useCORSPreflightFlag: true,
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    useCredentials: false,
    cache: 'default',
    redirect: 'follow',
    integrity: '',
    cryptoGraphicsNonceMetadata: '',
    parserMetadata: '',
    reloadNavigation: false,
    historyNavigation: false,
    userActivation: false,
    taintedOrigin: false,
    redirectCount: 0,
    responseTainting: 'basic',
    preventNoCacheCacheControlHeaderModification: false,
    done: false,
    timingAllowFailed: false,
    headersList: HeadersList {
      cookies: null,
      [Symbol(headers map)]: [Map],
      [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: [Array]
    },
    urlList: [ URL {} ],
    url: URL {
      href: 'http://localhost:3000/api/products/1',
      origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
      protocol: 'http:',
      username: '',
      password: '',
      host: 'localhost:3000',
      hostname: 'localhost',
      port: '3000',
      pathname: '/api/products/1',
      search: '',
      searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
      hash: ''
    }
  },
  [Symbol(signal)]: AbortSignal { aborted: false },
  [Symbol(headers)]: HeadersList {
    cookies: null,
    [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(15) {
      'accept' => [Object],
      'cache-control' => [Object],
      'connection' => [Object],
      'content-type' => [Object],
      'host' => [Object],
      'postman-token' => [Object],
      'transfer-encoding' => [Object],
      'user-agent' => [Object],
      'x-forwarded-for' => [Object],
      'x-forwarded-host' => [Object],
      'x-forwarded-port' => [Object],
      'x-forwarded-proto' => [Object],
      'x-invoke-path' => [Object],
      'x-invoke-query' => [Object],
      'x-middleware-invoke' => [Object]
    },
    [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: [
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array], [Array]
    ]
  },
  [Symbol(internal request)]: {
    cookies: RequestCookies { _parsed: Map(0) {}, _headers: [HeadersList] },
    geo: {},
    ip: undefined,
    nextUrl: NextURL { [Symbol(NextURLInternal)]: [Object] },
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/products/1'
  }
}
Here is the request body:
ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: false }
Here is the name and description:
undefined undefined
antesd de actualizar el supuestamente
{
  id: '1',
  name: 'prodcut name,
  description: 'descripcion',
  price: 200,
  image: 'https://i.ibb.co/pr9WFLs/36.jpg',
  category: 'C',
  tags: [],
  link: 'https://i.ibb.co/pr9WFLs/36.jpg',
  variantType: 'a',
  sizes: [],
  allOfSizes: [],
  status: 'sold',
  rating: '4.5',
  numberOfReviews: 150}
```

here when i try to log my request:

```
Here is the request body:
ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: false }
```

how can i solve this?

Comment: Would that answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40385133/retrieve-data-from-a-readablestream-object

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with this error today and the solution was to treat the request object before you use it. So, instead of:

```
const { name, description, price, image, category, tags, link, variantType, sizes, allOfSizes, status, rating, numberOfReviews } = await request.body;
```

try:

```
const { name, description, price, image, category, tags, link, variantType, sizes, allOfSizes, status, rating, numberOfReviews } = await request.json();
```

This is documented [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers#request-body).

This will only work on POST, PUT and PATCH methods that can receive a body on the request, if you trying to this in a DELETE transaction you will get the same error.