# Azure function nodejs: How can I extract the object from the request body in this azure function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

In nodejs azure function:

```
import {
  app,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpResponseInit,
  InvocationContext,
} from "@azure/functions";

export async function workerfunction(
  request: HttpRequest,
  context: InvocationContext
): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {
  context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);
  context.log("request.body: ", request.body);
```

I am testing in the azure portal:
Test body:

```
{"body":"this is a test message"}
```

And the printed message:

```
2023-08-02T06:49:19Z   [Information]   request.body:  ReadableStream { locked: true, state: 'closed', supportsBYOB: false }
```

Say I have a complex object in the request body that contains the data to be processed by my worker function, how can I read the object from the request body in this azure function?

Comment: found this answer that works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46912009/3703783

Answer (score 2):

> 2023-08-02T06:49:19Z   [Information]   request.body:  ReadableStream { locked: true, state: 'closed', supportsBYOB: false }

The issue is that you were logging a `ReadableStream` object instead of the actual content of the JSON object in the request body.

- You were logging the `request.body` directly, which is a `ReadableStream` object. This stream needs to be read and processed to get the actual content.
- Check the below code that you can be able to read and process the JSON object from the request body.

**Updated code:**

```js
import {
  app,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpResponseInit,
  InvocationContext,
} from "@azure/functions";

export async function workerfunction(
  context: InvocationContext,
  request: HttpRequest
): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {
  context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);

  try {
    const requestBody = request.body;

    context.log("request.body: ", requestBody);

    // Your processing logic using requestBody

    return {
      status: 200,
      body: "Request processed successfully",
    };
  } catch (error) {
    context.log.error("Error processing request:", error);

    return {
      status: 500,
      body: "Internal server error",
    };
  }
```

**Deployment status:**

[image]

Navigate to the function app in portal < HttpTrigger function.

[image]

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. There is a much shorter answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46912009/3703783  Is there any disadvantage in this short solution?

Comment: Using your code, I get this error: `error TS2339: Property 'on' does not exist on type 'HttpRequest'.`

Comment: I updated the above code with the given reference in you comment please check.