# wrapping nodejs stream in JSON object

Tags: json, node.js, stream, transform-stream

I have a readable stream, something like this:

```
const algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr';
stream = file.stream
    .pipe(crypto.createCipher(algorithm, encryptionKey))
    .pipe(outStream);
```

Encryption works as expected on the entire file.
I need to wrap the result of crypto into some sort of json, so the output stream to receive something like this:

```
{
    "content": "/* MY STREAM CONTENT */"
}
```

how do I do that?

Additionally, I need to read the file stored on disk and unwrap it from json if the encryption key matches.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing node.js stream into a string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623798/writing-node-js-stream-into-a-string-variable). I think that thread  tells you everything you need to know.

Comment: not really, my result after wrapping needs to be a stream, not a value stored in a variable. But thanks for your interest.

Comment: and I am expecting something more along the lines of a transform stream to write to the next stream at the end after wrapping, is that the right way to use streams? assuming everything stays in memory until the end of the read?

Comment: Yeah. That's what you need to do. It's just a variation of many of the examples on the web. Most transform an object. You want to construct one.

Comment: yeah, can you find some starting points I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of node v13, you can use [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) within [`pipeline`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_source_transforms_destination_callback) and build your object as a string:

```js
// const { pipeline } = require('stream/promises'); // <- node >= 16
const Util = require('util');
const pipeline = Util.promisify(Stream.pipeline);

const algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr';
const Crypto = require('crypto');

async function run() {
  await pipeline(
    file.stream, // <- your file read stream
    Crypto.createCipher(algorithm, encryptionKey),
    chunksToJson,
    outStream
  );
}

async function* chunksToJson(chunksAsync) {
  yield '{"content": "';
  for await (const chunk of chunksAsync) {
    yield Buffer.isBuffer(chunk) ? chunk.toString('utf8') : JSON.stringify(chunk);
  }
  yield '"}';
}
```

Assuming a more complex case where a large amount of data is being streamed (which is usually the case when using streams), you may be tempted to do something like the following. This is not a good practice since all of the `content` will build up in memory before yielding, defeating the purpose of streaming.

```js
async function* chunksToJson(chunksAsync) {
  const json = { content: [] };
  for await (const chunk of chunksAsync) {
    json.content.push(Buffer.isBuffer(chunk) ? chunk.toString('utf8') : JSON.stringify(chunk));
  }
  yield JSON.stringify(json);
}
```