# ReadableStream's 'data' event isn't emitted if stream is not piped beforehand

Tags: node.js, promise, ftp, stream

I'm using the `promise-ftp` Node.js library to download a file from an FTP server. Function `ftpClient.get(...)` returns a Promise of ReadableStream, data of which should be accessible using `data` and `end events`, however, I encounter a weird behaviour that is not described in the documentation.

```
//Some code that returns a to-be-downloaded file's name
.then((fileName) => {
    return ftpClient.get(fileName)
})
.then((fileStream) => {            
    let chunks = [];

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fileStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });
        fileStream.on('end', () => {
            resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf8'));
        });
    });
});
```

This is a solution on how to read a stream into a variable that I derived from answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623798/read-contents-of-node-js-stream-into-a-string-variable). However, it doesn't work: the `data` and `end events` are just never emitted.

Comparing my code to [this example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-ftp) in library documentation, the only difference is that the ReadableStream **is piped** somewhere beforehand.

Now, if I add `fileStream.pipe(...)`,

```
//...
.then((fileStream) => {

    fileStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('foo.txt'));
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    let chunks = [];

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
//...
```

everything works perfectly.

So my question is: what exactly is the purpose of adding a `.pipe()` and how is it connected to `data` and `end events`?

Answer (score 0):

**Pipe** is the correct way to read data from a stream. The idea comes from Linux Pipes. Something like:

```
fileStream | stdout
```

Here `fileStream` is being `pipe`'d to `stdout`

`on` is to register an event listener i.e. if some part of the program has the pipe set up, you can **listen in** to the same.

Not streaming any data when no one is reading it (i.e. its not being piped to anything) is an obvious optimisation *(it could have other constraints too)*.

Yes I understand the mentioned answer can be misleading. Office node docs on [streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streampipelinestreams-options) is better. And there is a new upward trending better [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63361543/1396264).