# How to use JSONStream.stringify to create a string (not a file)

Tags: javascript, json, npm, stream

Since my Google-Fu is failing me, I simply want to know:

How can I use `JSONStream.stringify()` to create a string containing JSON. I can find hundreds of examples that create a file, but none that simply create a string.

Edit: my usecase is that I have a large list of objects (and sometimes a small list of very large objects) which I need to turn into a JSON string. JSON.stringify cops out with a `RangeError: Invalid string length`, which is why I want to use `JSONStream`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read the contents of a Node.js stream into a string variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623798/how-do-i-read-the-contents-of-a-node-js-stream-into-a-string-variable)

Comment: Thanks for looking that up but sadly it's a different scenario. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Your file is too large to store it in a variable